# Setting a Differential equation for a simple math problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A saline solution contains $0.05\rm\,kg/liter $ salt. 
>   The saline solution flows into another tank with the speed of $3\rm\,liter/min$. What speed (in units $\rm kg/min$) is salt supplied to the tank?

**My answer:**

$$+3\rm\frac{liter}{min} \times 0.05 \frac{kg}{liter}=0.15 \frac{kg}{min},~~v=?$$

The salt is added to the tank with the speed of $0.15\rm\,kg/min$ - which is the correct answer.

But is there any way to describe this with a differential equation?

Comment: You don't need differential equations to combine ratio and units information. Only multiplication was necessary. It certainly sounds like it could be the initial *setup* to a forthcoming related rates problem, requiring differential equations to solve, though. | Also, it looks like you want $$3\cdot 0.005=0.\color{Red}015,$$ unless the given value was $0.05$, not $0.005$ as in your first sentence.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I have to answer with a differential equation. Maybe something like y=Ce^(-ax). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes you are right. I have mistyped it. is 0,05kg salt per liter. Sorry. I fixed it now.

Comment: Well, you've computed the rate-of-change of the liters of salt in the tank (unless liquid *also* flows *out* of the tank), so setting the derivative of liters-of-salt-in-the-tank equal to this rate would be a valid differential equation.

Comment: I dont understand. Sorry. Nothing flows out of the tank. The tank is empty at first, then the saline solution (salt+water) is added to tank (3 liter per minute).

Comment: An ordinary differential equation involves derivatives of a dependent variable (like $y$) with respect to an independent variable (like $x$). Here the relevant variables are `liters of salt in the tank` and `time`. You know the rate of change of the first variable with respect to the second - indeed, it is a constant - so just set the derivative equal to that number as an equality and you've written down a differential equation describing the situation.

Comment: anon, please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. I understand it now. You described it beautifully. Thanks you anon.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ordinary differential equation involves derivatives of a dependent variable (like $y$) with respect to an independent variable (like $x$). Here the two relevant variables are `liters of salt in the tank` and `time`. You know the rate of change of the first variable with respect to the second (indeed, it is a constant) so just set the derivative (of the first variable wrt the second, of course) equal to this known rate and you've written down a differential equation describing the situation.

Answer (score 0):

here the involved variables are linearly dependent...so while in calculation you are simply multiplying the rate,it is actually a multiplication by dy/dt...basically it is a very trivial kind of differential equation.you are forgeting that the rate you are talking about is basically a derivative...